# How to install a template in Joomla?

Tags: joomla-3.6

I have downloaded a free template for Joomla, but I do not know how to install it.

I saw on some forums I had to log in as administrator and in the Extensions menu, select "Extensions manager". But I got lost. Can you provide me with some detailed steps on how to do that?

Comment: If one of the answers below helped you to solve your problem, please award the green tick to the answer that you feel is best.  Otherwise, please ask the volunteers who have posted here to offer more specific details and explain where you are stuck.

Answer (score 2):

From https://www.gavick.com/documentation/joomla/tutorials/how-to-install-joomla-template-manually

### To install Joomla template follow these steps:

1. Login to your Joomla admin area as normal
2. click on **Install Extensions** in the left menu, or **Extensions → Extension Manager** in the top menu.
3. Once in the Extension Manager click on the Upload Package File tab
   Click on the C
4. Click on the **Choose file** button and select your downloaded template package for upload
5. Once selected, hit the **Upload & Install** button to get started.
   Wait a few seconds and the template should be uploaded and installed, ready for you to use.
   That tutorial also has alternate instructions for a manual installation using the **Discover** tool.

Answer (score 0):

The official instructions are at: https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Installing_a_template

Sorry for the link only answer but the official Joomla Documentation is more likely to be kept up to date than anything I copy into this answer.